# Is it possible to map a pattern-restricted simpleType to an enum class?

Tags: java, enums, xsd, jaxb

I was trying to map a pattern-restricted simpleType

```
<xs:simpleType name="exampleType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="\d{3,6}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

to an enum class (with values based on some specification document):

```
<jaxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='ExampleType']">
  <jaxb:typesafeEnumClass name="EnumExample">
    <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember value="1" name="description_1" />
    ....
  </jaxb:typesafeEnumClass>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

but got

```
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: enum class customization is specified on a type that has no enumeration facet.
```

Is that or something similar possible somehow?

Comment: Your pattern allows almost 10 million different values for exampleType. I don't understand why you want to treat that type as an _enumeration_.

Comment: @kimbert there is a specification document describing the possible values

Comment: @kimbert 10 million? ""\d{3,6}" (3 to 6 digits) sounds like 1000 values to me. Nevertheless, it's not suitable for an enumeration.

Comment: @ChristophDahlen it's a real world scenario. we have no control over the schema. the documentation defines 6 possible values, which is why i would like to have an enum.

Comment: You're right. 6 digits is 000000..999999, so 1 million. The pattern requires at least 3 digits, so the pattern allows (1 million - 1 hundred) values.

Comment: unrelated, but i believe the number of possible values for `\d{3,6}` is `10^3 + 10^4 + 10^5 + 10^6`

Answer (score 0):

Your data type only allows 6 values. Instead of using xs:pattern you should be using xs:enumeration. You have not quoted the values, so I have made up some values as an example:

```
<xs:simpleType name="exampleType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="100"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="2000"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="30000"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="400000"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="100001"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="999999"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: like i said, we have no control over the schema. we get the schema and the docs, and have to generate valid data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of letting JAXB generate an enum based on XSD enumeration values, it seems to be possible to map a custom enum class:

```
<jaxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='customType']">
  <jaxb:class ref="com.package.EnumCustom" />
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Manually written:

```
@XmlType(name = "")
@XmlEnum
public enum EnumCustom {
  @XmlEnumValue("111")    VALUE_A,
  @XmlEnumValue("111222") VALUE_B,
  ...
  ;
}
```